# Mac OS X Xcode Libraries

Tags: xcode

Tired of having to change my header and library search paths in every project to be able to link libraries from homebrew in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`.

Is there a way to make Xcode recognize those two search paths by default? `ld` states it uses those search paths by default but it seems Xcode does not.

Also, is there a way to add my libraries from `/usr/local/lib` to this dialog without having to select add other?

[image: add library dialog]

Comment: I could help with GCC, but it seems that recent Xcode is based on LLVM / Clang instead.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Well, Xcode lets you decided whether to compile in GNU (GCC) mode or CLANG mode in a project's settings, but that is not relevant to my question as my question is about changing Xcode's settings themselves. As a hint to others more knowledgeable in this area, there is probably a way to do this by editing some of Xcode's files, maybe some plist file? Not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add default [include and search paths](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) that persist across all projects, you need to use:

For include paths:

```
CPATH
C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
```

And for library paths:

```
LIBRARY_PATH
```

In order for Xcode and other GUI applications in OS X (tested on 10.10) to be able to access these environment variables, you need to set variables using:

```
/bin/launchctl setenv LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
/bin/launchctl setenv CPATH /usr/local/include
```

But these are not permanent. In order to have these variables across restarts, you need to create a startup script. [See this page for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/25912736#25912736)

This is my personal applescript file which I have saved as an Application in iCloud (so it survives reformats) and have set as a startup item in system preferences->users and groups->login items.

```
set ENV_LIBRARY_PATH to "/bin/launchctl setenv LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib;"
set ENV_CPATH to "/bin/launchctl setenv CPATH /usr/local/include;"
do shell script ENV_LIBRARY_PATH & ENV_CPATH
```

---

As for adding them to the dialog, there are two ways which i have found:

1. The quick and dirty way: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib`

   This will add all of your lib files from /usr/local/lib to the dialog under the same OS X 10.10 "folder" in the dialog.
2. The second way involves creating your own .sdk directory with a usr
   subdirectory in
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`,
   then copying over the SDKSettings.plist from
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/SDKSettings.plist`
   to your .sdk directory, editing it using Xcode, and symlinking your
   /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib to your
   mydir.sdk/usr/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to make Xcode recognize those two search paths by default?

> "Can you please tell me how to add include path and library path in  XCode project?"
>
> You're looking for "Header Search Path" and "Library Search Paths."
>
> Use the handy search field at the top to find them.
>
> Also, make sure the "Show" pop-up is set to "All Settings".
>
> If it's set to one of the other values, then you won't necessarily see
> the setting you're looking for.

[image]

Source [How to add include path and library path in XCode project](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Jul/msg00292.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [Helping Xcode Find Library Headers](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/helping-xcode-find-library-headers/)

Comment: My question asks for setting default search paths (that are always searched regardless of per-project settings). See my question, and answer below for the solution.